# Using BasedOn property with a Style defined in a different dictionary

Tags: c#, silverlight, resourcedictionary, mergeddictionaries

The application I'm working on has 2 ResourceDictionary, DefaultStyles.xaml and CustomStyles.xaml.

Is it possible that a style in the CustomStyles dictionary uses a base style defined in the other dictionary?

**DefaultStyles.xaml:**

```
<Style x:Key="TextBlockDefaultStyle" TargetType="TextBlock">  
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="4" />  
</Style>
```

**CustomStyles.xaml:**

```
<Style x:Key="SectionTitleStyle" TargetType="TextBlock" BasedOn="{StaticResource TextBlockDefaultStyle}">
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16" />
</Style>
```

**App.xaml:**

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Assets/Styles/DefaultStyles.xaml"/>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Assets/Styles/CustomStyles.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

When the code runs, the following exception is thrown:

Cannot find a Resource with the Name/Key TextBlockDefaultStyle.

It works well if both styles are in the same file.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to reference the dictionary with the other style directly.

**CustomStyles.xaml:**

```
<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="DefaultStyles.xaml" />
</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

<Style x:Key="SectionTitleStyle" TargetType="TextBlock" BasedOn="{StaticResource TextBlockDefaultStyle}">
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16" />
</Style>
```

Comment: This behavior is reasonable.But I just had another problem: BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Button}}" wasn't working until I changed it to reference by key instead of type. This one looks like bug in WPF runtime.

Comment: Per @alehro's comment, I worked around the issue by moving the `<Style>`s into the resources of a panel just inside my window. Then `BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Button}}"` worked.