# WPF. Set BasedOn property with a resource from a different dictionary

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm relatively new to WPF. I have two dictionaries with style definitions which I later use in XAML views.

The base style (in `CommonStyles.xaml`):

```
    <ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyProject.Theme">
    <...>
    <Style x:Key="RoundCornerButton" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <...>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

The specific style (what I've have tried) (in `SpecificStyles.xaml`):

```
    <ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyProject.Theme">
    <...>
    <Style x:Key="RoundCornerButtonWithCheck" TargetType="{x:Type Button}" BasedOn="{StaticResource RoundCornerButton}">
        <...>
    </style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

What I want to do is to use the style `RoundCornerButton` defined within `CommonStyles.xaml` as the "parent" style of `RoundCornerButtonWithCheck` in `SpecificStyles.xaml`, I mean, as the value of `BasedOn` property (kind of inheritance).

I've also tried setting the property `BasedOn` this way:
`BasedOn="{StaticResource {local:Style RoundCornerButton}}"`

As `CommonStyles.xaml` is inside the folder Theme/ inside MyProject/, I thought I could access it through `local:` namespace in some way,
but I'm not sure how to do this.

I've been looking at the documentation of [`BasedOn`](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.windows.style.basedon?view=netframework-4.7.2) property as well as [other resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4649626/using-basedon-property-with-a-style-defined-in-a-different-dictionary), but I'm still confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to be able to reference a resource defined in `CommonStyles.xaml` in `SpecificStyles.xaml` using the `StaticResource` markup extension, you should merge the former `ResourceDictionary` into the latter:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="CommonStyles.xaml" />
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

    <Style x:Key="RoundCornerButtonWithCheck" TargetType="{x:Type Button}" BasedOn="{StaticResource RoundCornerButton}">
        ...
    </Style>


</ResourceDictionary>
```